# Emitting column data from reducer as a row

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, reducers

I am trying to process a csv file.
`In map()` I will be sending each column as a value to reducer.
`In reducer` I will be finding the min and max and further processing .After processing i need to context .write the value.But trying to output in a specific manner.

In reducer I am processing each column but i need to output the entire `row`
ie values of col1 ,values of col2, values of col3,values of col4.

**Sample data after processing from reducer**

```
in reducer
0.62
0.38
0.9
in reducer
0.24
0.59
0.1
in reducer
0.5
1.0
0.2
in reducer
0.0
0.0
0.3
```

**Expected output**

```
 0.62,0.24,0.5,0.5
 0.38,0.59,1.0,0.0
 0.9,0.1,0.2,0.3
```

Is it possible to handle each different key in reducer for each iteration

```
key1value1,key2value1,key3value1
key1value2,key2value2,key3value2
```

Any suggesions

Comment: write 2 different reducer for max and min,and combine both reducer result in one file

Comment: @Alkesh_IT: No it is not the output of min and max.After min and max I am applying some equations too .after that i am getting the above result.I need to combine that result

Comment: Is there any way to access different keys in Reducer at a tym and emit the each key value as one line?

Comment: No idea,but may be it's not possible because of records partitioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MapReduce chaining you can Perform this

write reducer output in single line using Text type
Like

```
0.62,0.38,0.9
0.24,0.59,0.1
```

and again perform mapreduce on output file of first MapReduce.

```
public void map(Text key, Text value,OutputCollector<Text, Text> output,
Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
  String temp=new String(value);
  String token[]=temp.split(",");
  output.collect(new Text("max"),new text(token[0]));
  output.collect(new Text("min"),new text(token[1]));
  output.collect(new Text("result"),new text(token[2]));
}

public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values,
    OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter)
    throws IOException {
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
while (values.hasNext())
   sb.append(values.next().toString() + ",");
output.collect(new Text(""),new Text(sb.toString()))



}
```

Comment: But this output is different from my expectation.I am trying to get output as 0.62,0.24,0.5,0.5 \n
 0.38,0.59,1.0,0.0 \n
 0.9,0.1,0.2,0.3 \n

Comment: But here the 1 st row is key 1 and 2 nd row is key 2 how to get its transpose.ie key1,key2 \nkey1,key2